# optimizing my page for smaller screen resolutions

Tags: css, drupal, html

I'm having issues to optimize my page for smaller screen resolutions.
When I take my browser window (Google Chrome) and shrink it, the menu bar pops onto a second line way before there's no more room for it on top. i would like the black area on the left of the logo to shrink first to be aligned with the content box and then only once there's no more room for the content, there also is no more room for logo and menu on top... but how can I get this achieved I'm wondering?
Thanks for help!

The url:
http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/?q=lodge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to remove the inner padding on the left side of the logo and instead give the "toplogo"  a fixed width (in pixels) with auto margin on either side to get it centered on the page. That seems to give me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use CSS3 media queries. Using them you can specify separate styles for different browser sizes.
More info about responsive design you can find here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

Comment: Oh Thanks, I'll sure read up on that too but I was able toshift around css properties so that it works, I actually had to remove the inner paddingon the left side of the logo and instead give the "toplogo" <div> a fix width with auto margin on either side. That seems to give me pretty much what I wanted. But thanks again for that link, interesting to read up on that too!